# How to upload List of images on azure and retrieve addresses of uploaded images

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, parallel-processing, azure-blob-storage

I am doing Mvc asp.net project. i want to upload four images on azure blob storage, i am uploading one image at a time using following method

```
     public static string UploadToBlob(string fileName, byte[] data)
     {
        MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream(data);
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ConnectionSetting"));
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
        // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        blob.UploadFromStream(file);
        string url = blob.Uri.ToString();
        return url;
    }
```

it's takes four call to azure server, so i want do it in one call i.e  upload List of four images on azure and retrieve  addresses of uploaded images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make separate service calls to upload separate blobs. However, you should be sharing most of the common code in that method. Namely, everything above actually getting the blob reference. This will save you several service calls by only calling CreateIfNotExists on the container once.

Comment: Yes, above code gives the blob reference but, i want to know is there any way that will gives reference for list of Blobs. i.e like array

Comment: Do you know the names of blobs that are there in your container for which you want to get the references?

Comment: Yes i know the names of blobs ,  Actually i have four images to upload ,i am uploading one image at a time and azure storage gives me the url of uploaded image so it takes 4 separate calls. Now i want to upload four image at one's i.e it should take one call only.

Comment: As Emily mentioned, you will need to make 4 separate calls. In one call to Azure Storage, you will only be able to upload 1 file at a time. What you could do is refactor your code so that you only execute common code of creating the container only once (again as mentioned by Emily).

Comment: Ok.  i got it, Thank you Emily and Gaurav